# GNU Make wildcard to compile each file separately into a build directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to create the following directory structure for a C++ project.

```
├── Project
├── Makefile
│   ├── build/
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   ├── cpp/
│   │   loader.s
│   │   linker.ld
```

I also want to compile each `.cpp` file separately into the **build** directory and link in a different target.

I am having trouble with the wildcard to do this:

```
BUILD    = ./build/
OBJS     = $(patsubst src/cpp/%.cpp,build/%.o,$(wildcard src/cpp/*.cpp))
CPPFLAGS = -I ./src/include -Wfatal-errors -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore

$(BUILD)kernel.elf: $(BUILD)loader.o $(OBJS)
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -T ./src/linker.ld -o $@ $^
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D $(BUILD)kernel.elf > $(BUILD)kernel.list

$(BUILD)%.o: ./src/%.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

$(BUILD)%.o: ./src/cpp/%.cpp
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

The `build/%.o`'s are never built so the link step gets an empty `$(OBJS)`. What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Try setting `BUILD` to `build/`. That `./` prefix might break rule matching. I also don't think $(OBJS) is empty, you can check it with `$(info $(OBJS))`.

Comment: That exactly did it!! Nice one! Can you please add answer so I can accept it? Or should I remove the question?

Comment: I don't really know under which conditions questions should be removed. I think this isn't the first time the answer is to make paths match, so it might be closed as a duplicate, if somebody finds similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BUILD` variable is set to `./build/`, while object files in `OBJ` start with `build/`.  After expansion rules look like:

```
./build/kernel.elf: ./build/loader.o build/...
./build/%.o: ./src/%.s
```

That additional `./` prefix affects rule matching by `make`, because paths aren't normalized.

The fix is as simple as making prefixes in target goals and prerequisites match by setting:

```
BUILD = build/
```